# tableviews scrolls very slowly because of a UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-server, pfquery

I have a PFQueryTableViewController, and I'm loading images, but when I do my table view scrolls extremely slowly or at times not at all. But when I remove the code to load the image in background, the table view scrolls normally. I'm loading the PFImageView in the background so I don't know why it's scrolling so slowly.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ProductTableViewCell

    if let files : [PFFile] = object?["Images"] as? [PFFile] {
        cell.ProductImage.file = files.first
        cell.ProductImage.loadInBackground()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code for your `loadInBackground()` function?

Comment: Very often I've run into an issue with `UIImage`s but I think that using pre-fetching might be the solution.

There's a nice WWDC session from last year - https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/219/. Don't worry it says it's for `UICollectionView`, the `UITableView` has this API too.

Comment: @Robert I can't include the code for loadinbackground because its part of a call for pfquerytableviewcontroller

Comment: cell.ProductImage.loadInBackground()
please add code of that func too

Comment: @Optimus It's open source: https://github.com/parse-community/ParseUI-iOS/blob/master/ParseUI/Classes/Views/PFImageView.m#L50